# Alternative ways to create file scope in Unity Builds

Tags: c++, build

I'm trying to use Unity Builds to shorten the build time of a c++ project on Windows. One of several problems I met is the single file scope issue.

Once all source codes are included in a single source file, they all share the same file scope. All locally defined symbols using same name will be duplicate and causing compile errors.

Currently, I have to change each duplicated names with a file postfix to avoid duplication. But I think there might be better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share my current solution.

1. In generation of `unity_build_source_<index>.cpp` files, define a `UNITY_BUILD` macro and wrap each include source code with macros:

   ```
   // unity_build_souce file, automatically generated, do not edit manually.
   #define UNITYBUILD_CONCATENATE_DETAIL(x, y) x##y
   #define UNITYBUILD_CONCATENATE(x, y) UNITYBUILD_CONCATENATE_DETAIL(x, y)
   #define UNITYBUILD_MAKE_UNIQUE(x) UNITYBUILD_CONCATENATE(x, _UNITYBUILD_COUNTER)
   #define UNITY_BUILD

   // for each source code
   #define _UNITY_BUILD_COUNTER 1
   #include <path/to/source1.cpp>
   #undef _UNITY_BUILD_COUNTER

   #define _UNITY_BUILD_COUNTER 2
   #include <path/to/source2.cpp>
   #undef _UNITY_BUILD_COUNTER

   // ...
   ```
2. In source codes, use UNITYBUILD_MAKE_UNIQUE macro for names that is duplicated.

   ```
   #ifdef UNITY_BUILD
   #define a_duplicated_variable      UNITYBUILD_MAKE_UNIQUE(a_duplicated_variable)
   #define ADuplicatedClass           UNITYBUILD_MAKE_UNIQUE(ADuplicatedClass)
   #define aDuplicatedFunction        UNITYBUILD_MAKE_UNIQUE(aDuplicatedFunction)
   #endif

   namespace
   {
       int a_duplicated_variable = 3;
       class ADuplicatedClass
       {
       public:
            ADuplicatedClass(int ){}
       };
   }

   void aDuplicatedFunction()
   {
       ADuplicatedClass c(a_duplicated_variable);
   }

   #ifdef UNITY_BUILD
   #undef a_duplicated_variable
   #undef ADuplicatedClass
   #undef aDuplicatedFunction
   #endif
   ```

I know this solution is still bad looking. Compared with manually change each duplicated symbols, it keeps the old names the look as they were.